# Updating a TextView in a ViewPager Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

In my Android app, I'm having trouble setting a TextView that is located in a fragment from the parent activity. I am using a ViewPager as follows:

In my main activity's onCreate():

```
List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, MainPageProfileFragment.class.getName()));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, MainPageOtherFragment.class.getName()));
mainPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
pager.setAdapter(mainPagerAdapter);
```

with the ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    private List<Fragment> fragments;
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super (fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        return this.fragments.get(arg0);
    }
}
```

And the MainPageProfileFragment below. This fragment provides an interface to update a TextView at runtime (after the view is created).

```
public class MainPageProfileFragment extends Fragment
    implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView profileImageLabelTextView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(container == null) {
            return null;
        }
        ScrollView view = (ScrollView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_page_profile, container, false);
        labelTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.profileLabel);
        return view;
    }
    public void setLabelText(String text) {
        labelTextView.setText(text);
    }
}
```

The setLabelTextView() I'd like to call from the main activity's onResume() handler, but I haven't yet been able to get a handle on the fragment that would allow me to access this method. I'm going a bit in circles now as I have found different approaches for accessing views in fragments where this seemed to be the most plausible but I haven't succeeded yet. How would I call the setLabelText() method from my activity?

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // set the labelTextView here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straitforward way would be to lookup `ViewPager`, then take `ViewPagerAdapter` and then try to get the fragment. If fragment is there, you can call `setLabelText()` method. Something like this.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = (ViewPagerAdapter) pager.getAdapter();
    Fragment fragment = adapter.getItem(0);
    if (fragment instanceof MainPageProfileFragment) {
        // if we are here, then fragment is not null and has correct type
        ((MainPageProfileFragment)fragment).setLabelText("my text");
    }
}
```

To add `getItem()` method to an `Adapter`, you should extend `FragmentPagerAdapter` and track list of Fragments by your own. Like this

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

But a more elegant and flexible solution would be to use a event bus for `Activity` to `Fragment` communication. There are some event buses implementation out there. You can try [TinyBus](https://github.com/beworker/tinybus) or [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. This looks like it's going to work. I ran into the next problem that the fragment apparently is not inflated yet, resulting in an exception when the page is created. Upon return to the page from the activity stack everything is in place. Perhaps OnResume() isn't the right place for this as that is called also when the view is initially created. It's a bit late here now but I will have a look at this as well as the event buses first thing tomorrow morning. Thanks again.

Comment: The best option is to use event bus. It decouples Activity from Fragment and solves lifecycle issues. Activity registers itself and provides string onto the bus. When fragment is there, it gets the string pushed from the bus. Any other fragment interested in same string will get it too with almost no code. It's really simpler in long run to use an event bus.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check that out. I have verified the first solution setting a simple flag indicating initial create vs. return from paused state. The rest is just figuring out where to put my code. But I will definitely reconsider this based on your advice.

Comment: Where is the example with event bus?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is the best solution but you could try to retrieve the fragment by tag name using the internal name:

```
"android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + index;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                ViewPagerAdapter adapter = (ViewPagerAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter();
                Fragment fragment = adapter.getItem(position);
                if (fragment instanceof BiographyFragment) {
                    // if we are here, then fragment is not null and has correct type
                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        ((BiographyFragment) fragment).mTextViewBiography.setText(fromHtml(mBiography, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
                    } else {
                        ((BiographyFragment) fragment).mTextViewBiography.setText(fromHtml(mBiography));
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```